# Get "original" (non-hover) background color of object when hovering over it

Tags: jquery, css

I can get the background color of any element with the following functions:

```
$('.example').css('background')
```

However, in my case, the mouse is moving over this element and I receive a modified color because of a CSS `:hover` pseudo-class.

Is there any way to receive original color? Something like

```
$('.example').cssWithoutHover('background')
```

You can test it [here](http://sudokuhero.com/5J2763E1I6HI14593C413JC85HGC6948B7531I5D726J47D46F928195123E8678C75B6D49D4GI971C0). Just put 5 in the last cell. The color of this cell will change after animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a sweep of the starting BG colours on DOM ready and store these as data attributes.

```
var board = $('#board-numbers');
board.children('div').each(function() {
    $(this).data('start-bg', $(this).css('background'));
});
board.on('hover', 'div', function() {
    var curr_bg = $(this).css('background');
    var start_bg = $(this).data('start-bg');
});
```

Comment: The problem with this kind of solution, is that it requires a memory overhead (to store the background-colors of objects which you may never need to use), and processor intensive, in the sense that you have to sweep the DOM every time you load the page. Given the way that JavaScript/JQuery works with asynchronous page-loads, you may also "miss" caching-up the background colours, if the original `<div>` object was loaded via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the idea posted by @vadim, I think I can go one better.  Simply `clone()` the object, and don't put it in the DOM.  that way it cannot be hovered over!

```
css_color_without_hover_ = $('.example').clone(false).css('background');
```

Saves you having to do a potentially expensive sweep of the DOM upon document-load as well!

Works nicely for me anyhoo.

-- EDIT --

I've just noticed that there are limitations (or 'gotchas') to this technique.

If the element for which you're trying to get the color-data, has its color (or background-color) inherited from a parent element, then the cloned object won't match the CSS pattern, meaning that the styling won't get applied to the jQuery object.

The work-around in this case, is to clone the parent object instead (to which the appropriate styling does apply), and fetch its styling, rather than the child's.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certain you can't as easily.

Here're a derived solutions to do it :

After the page loading, you can store the background-color in a custom attribute (which won't change on hover) to be able to get it later :

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.example').each(function(el){
        $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('background-color'));
    });
    $('.example').hover(function(ev){
        console.log($(this).data('bgcolor'));
    });
}):
```

Comment: use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `attr()` to not invalidate your html.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [jss](https://github.com/Box9/jss) library. it gives you access to the stylesheet rules

Comment: May be overkill for a one-off example such as presented in the original question.  But if you do a lot of this kind of CSS manipulation on your website, it's worth keeping this kind of solution in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to move all background colors definition to different classes. And when you need background color for specific class you can create element on-the-fly and get it background color and it will be without :hover modification. Something like that:

```
$('<div class="normal-cell"></div>').css('background-color')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use jQuery [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to change the style on hover rather than pure CSS.  For example,

```
$('.example').hover(
    function() { // handlerIn
        $(this).addClass('exampleHover');
    },
    function() { // handlerOut
        $(this).removeClass('exampleHover');
    }
);
```